# Error when trying to Edit View of library

Tags: 404

When navigating to document library settings - edit view (without doing anything) selected ok redirects me to the following page with an error

```
http://{nodename}:47437/sites/Test2/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001
```

Looking at the sharepoint iis log i see the following

> 2011-06-01 19:25:53 172.22.1.11 POST /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll CS=65001
>   47437 {domain\username} 172.22.1.11
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+InfoPath.3;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+MS-RTC+EA+2;+MS-RTC+LM+8)
>   404 0 0 13

Any ideas?

I am running SharePoint 2010 on windows 7 box

**UPDATE:**

1. I checked in IIS Manager that ASP.NET and Windows SharePoint Services extensions are allowed.
2. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll` seems OK.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what you are doing because I've tried editing a view of a document library and in fiddler I do not get any fprpc call to owssvr.dll

Comment: Is the document library custom in anyway, are there any additional web parts added to the editform.aspx page? Do you have any custom HTTPModules installed on the web application?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please [edit] your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.